# how to catch php E_PARSE error with custom error handler?

Tags: php, exception

I tried using `register_shutdown` and `set_error_handler` together but no luck.Does anyone know another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

here is a snippet from the documentations

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined
>   function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING,
>   E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the
>   file where set_error_handler() is called.

`E_PARSE` stops the execution immediately so it will have no way to call any other function

Comment: E_ERROR stops the execution too but it is possible to catch E_ERROR within register_shutdown() function using error_get_last() function and call custom error handler with that error.but it doesnt work with E_PARSE error.so register_shutdown() is not called when E_PARSE error happened?